# Conditional independence of sigma-algebras: equivalent characterisations.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, independence

Conditional independence of events $A,B$ given a nonnegligible event $C$ is defined as $\mathbb{P}(A|B,C)=\mathbb{P}(A|C)$. This is equivalent to $\mathbb{P}(A,B|C)=\mathbb{P}(A|C)\mathbb{P}(B|C)$. When we move onto random variables, we use this second characterisation: we say that random variables $X,Y$ are independent conditionally on random variable $W$ if for every $A\in\sigma(X)$ and $B\in \sigma(Y)$, $\mathbb{P}(A,B|\sigma(W))=\mathbb{P}(A|\sigma(W))\mathbb{P}(B|\sigma(W))$ a.s.

My question is: does the first characterisation still hold? I.e. is it true that this is equivalent to $\mathbb{P}(A|\sigma(Y,W))=\mathbb{P}(A|\sigma(W))$ for all $A\in\sigma(X)$? How do we prove/disprove it? Here I denoted $\sigma(Y,W)=\sigma(\sigma(Y)\cup\sigma(W))$. Thanks for any help.

My attempt: perhaps it suffices (but by what standard argument?) to show this for generators of the sigma-algebras involved. Denote with $B$ a generic generator of $\sigma(Y)$ and $C$ a generator of $\sigma(W)$. Assuming that $B\cap C$ describes a generic generator of $\sigma(Y,W)$, the result is true by the characterisation given for events. Thus the problem seems to boil down to whether $\sigma(Y,W)$ is truly generated by sets $B\cap C$ for $B$ a generator of $\sigma(Y)$ and $C$ a generator of $\sigma(W)$. I know how to show that in general $\sigma(Y,W)$ is generated by all the possible intersections of the sets in $\sigma(Y)$ and $\sigma(W)$, but I am not sure if we can consider JUST the intersections of the generators of the two and still get $\sigma(Y,W)$.

Comment: You already gave me the answer which will deter future answers. In general it is a good idea to wait to give the answer to any proposal since that will attract more traffic. You may end up learning one or two extra things, and those who write answer may gain a few extra points.

Comment: Apologies, your answer was very clear and exhaustive, so I thought there was no need to wait, the post had been pretty much ignored for a whole day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characterisation is true. In fact, random variables are not needed.

**Theorem.** Let $\mathscr{A},$ $\mathscr{B}$ and $\mathscr{F}$ be three sigma fields. A necessary and sufficient condition for
$$
P(A \cap B \mid \mathscr{F}) = P(A \mid \mathscr{F}) P(B \mid \mathscr{F}) \qquad \forall A \in \mathscr{A}, B \in \mathscr{B}
$$
is that
$$
P(A \mid \mathscr{B} \vee \mathscr{F}) = P(A \mid \mathscr{F}).
$$
(As it is somewhat common, $\mathscr{B} \vee \mathscr{F} = \sigma(\mathscr{B} \cup \mathscr{F})$.)

*Proof of sufficiency.* Consider $A$ and $B$ as in the statement. The definition and $\mathscr{F}$-measurability imply,
$$
P(A \mid \mathscr{F}) P(B \mid \mathscr{F}) = E(\mathbf{1}_B E(\mathbf{1}_A \mid \mathscr{F}) \mid \mathscr{F});
$$
the hypothesis allows replacing $E(\mathbf{1}_A \mid \mathscr{F})$ by $E(\mathbf{1}_A \mid \mathscr{B} \vee \mathscr{F}),$ then $\mathbf{1}_B$ can enter this expectation by $(\mathscr{B} \vee \mathscr{F})$-measurability, so we get
$$
P(A \mid \mathscr{F}) P(B \mid \mathscr{F}) = E(E(\mathbf{1}_A \mathbf{1}_B \mid \mathscr{B} \vee \mathscr{F}) \mid \mathscr{F}) = E(\mathbf{1}_A \mathbf{1}_B \mid \mathscr{F}) = P(A \cap B \mid \mathscr{F}),
$$
the penultimate equality is the tower property of conditional expectation. Thus, sufficiency has been proved.

*Proof of necessity.* We are required to prove
$$
\begin{equation}\tag{*}
P(A \cap H) = \int\limits_H P(A \mid \mathscr{F})\ dP
\end{equation}
$$
for all $H \in \mathscr{B} \vee \mathscr{F}.$ Note that both sides in the equation above define measures on $H.$

The following can be proved as a basic exercise on sigma fields,
$$
\mathscr{B} \vee \mathscr{F} = \sigma\left( \left\{ \bigcup_{\alpha \in \Gamma} B_\alpha \cap F_\alpha \middle| B_\alpha \in \mathscr{B}, F_\alpha \in \mathscr{F} \right\} \right),
$$
the right hand side is the field of all *finite* unions of sets of the form $B \cap F.$ Now, monotone class theorem shows that suffices to prove (*) when $H = B \cap F.$ Then
$$
P(A \cap B \cap F) = \int\limits_F P(A \cap B \mid \mathscr{F})\ dP = \int\limits_F P(A \mid \mathscr{F})P(B \mid \mathscr{F})\ dP.
$$
Now, as above,
$$
P(A \mid \mathscr{F}) P(B \mid \mathscr{F}) = E(\mathbf{1}_B E(\mathbf{1}_A \mid \mathscr{F}) \mid \mathscr{F}),
$$
and integrating over a set in $\mathscr{F}$ will cancel out the last conditioning (by definition),
$$
P(A \cap B \cap F) = \int\limits_F \mathbf{1}_B E(\mathbf{1}_A \mid \mathscr{F})\ dP = \int\limits_{F \cap B} P(A \mid \mathscr{F})\ dP,
$$
completing the proof. QED